# Typescript constructor parameter undefined in method

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I'm trying to wrap my head around how to use Typescript and Angularjs together. I've read several blog posts and both projects' documentation but it isn't sticking.

I have an Angular controller that takes two dependencies, $scope and a service that I wrote called greetingService. I've defined a main app Angular module and attached the controller and service to it. I have log statements in my Typescript constructors so that I can inspect the dependencies in the browser. In the constructors of both my controller and my custom service, the dependencies are injected correctly. However, in the controller, when I try to use a dependency, it is undefined. I think this code snippet demonstrates the issue better than I can explain it.

```
declare var angular;

module App.Services {
    export class GreetingService {

        constructor(private $http) {
            console.log("In greeting service constructor");
            console.log($http);
        }

        getGreetingsPromise() {
            return this.$http.get('/greetings.json');
        }
    }
}

module App.Controllers {
    export class GreetingController {

        static $inject = ['$scope', 'greetingService'];
        constructor(public $scope, public greetingService: App.Services.GreetingService) {
            this.$scope.greeting = "This will be a greeting.";
            this.$scope.greet = this.greet;

            console.log(greetingService); // this is defined and looks right
        }

        greet(language: string) {
            console.log("Greeting...");
            console.log(this.$scope); // this is undefined
            console.log(this.greetingService); // this is undefined
            var greetingPromise = this.greetingService.getGreetingsPromise();
            greetingPromise.then(data => this.$scope.greeting = data[language]);
        }
    }
}


var mainApp = angular.module('mainApp', []);
mainApp.controller('greetingController', ['$scope', 'greetingService', App.Controllers.GreetingController]);
mainApp.service('greetingService', App.Services.GreetingService);
```

And here is the Angular template (that correctly displays "This will be a greeting" that is initialized in the constructor).

```
<div class="jumbotron">
    <div ng-controller="greetingController">
        <p class="lead">{{greeting}}</p>
        <button ng-click="greet('english')">Greet me</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line:

```
this.$scope.greet = this.greet
```

is the problem. You are just copying the function reference to a scope property and when it is called with scope `this` won't be the controller instance, it is determined by the caller (in your case, `this` should be the scope itself inside the `greet` function when it is called from the template) except for the bound functions. A quick fix would be to use [function.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind). i.e `this.$scope.greet = this.greet.bind(this)` with which you create a bound function, function reference bound to the controller instance. You could also use an arrow function and assign it as reference, this will force TS to convert any `this` to `_this` cached variable:

```
   greet = (language: string) => {
        console.log("Greeting...");
        console.log(this.$scope); // this is undefined
        console.log(this.greetingService); // this is undefined
        var greetingPromise = this.greetingService.getGreetingsPromise();
        greetingPromise.then(data => this.$scope.greeting = data[language]);
    }
```

Ideally if you use `controller As` (provided your angular supports it, if not highly recommended to upgrade) syntax rather than using scope directly you would not need do all these.

i.e:

```
export class GreetingController {
    greeting :string;

    static $inject = ['greetingService'];

    constructor(public greetingService: App.Services.GreetingService) {
        this.greeting = "This will be a greeting.";
    }

    greet(language: string) {
        var greetingPromise = this.greetingService.getGreetingsPromise();
        greetingPromise.then(data => this.greeting = data[language]);
    }
}
```

and

```
<div class="jumbotron">
    <div ng-controller="greetingController as vm">
        <p class="lead">{{vm.greeting}}</p>
        <button ng-click="vm.greet('english')">Greet me</button>
    </div>
</div>
```